# Slow motion stander rates

Tags: image-processing, video-streaming, frame-rate, slowmotion

I got videos from youtube that showing the soccer player while falling, most of these videos show the slow motion of the falling, I need the actual falling without the used slow motion.

the fps for most of these videos are 23, 25, 29 fps.

I have seen the two way of the stander slow motion, at this [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slow_motion).But how to see the original used rate for the previous videos.
Any suggestion?

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you have a slow motion video and you want to restore real-time speed? If yes, do you know how much slower your slow-motion video is?

Comment: No I didn't know, I have just got them from YouTube

Answer (score 1):

Generally the effect of slow-motion is produced by filming at a higher frame-rate and displaying the movie in a lower frame-rate. For instance, to get 2x slow-motion, you could record in 50fps and playback in 25fps.

You are saying that the slow-motion videos you have are in 23, 25, 29 fps. This is the playback rate. Originally they were recorded in higher frames-rates that are unknown to us. But we can try to restore the original speed by displaying more frames per second or by cutting out frames and see if it looks realistic. I had a look around and I could not find a what standard slow-motion frame-rates are. If you cannot find out either you will have to guess.

You can use `ffmpeg` to modify the framerate of your videos as described here https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/How%20to%20speed%20up%20/%20slow%20down%20a%20video . If you wanted to double the video playback speed (to restore from 2x slow-motion), you can do:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -filter:v "setpts=0.5*PTS" output.mkv
```

But I would recommend reading the short article in the link above to understand what this and the alternative commands are doing.

Comment: Thanks for help.
all ffmpeg downloads are source codes, I can't see executable file for windows?

Comment: On the ffmpeg side, you can download the source, but also the builds (installers): https://www.ffmpeg.org/download.html#build-windows points you to http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/ . You will want a static build.